# GET request on input field return None in Django

Tags: python, django, post, request

I'm trying to retrieve the data from the input fields. I want to export a .xls file where data are chosen between two dates. The problem is that I am getting "None" as a value when I try to retrieve them.

.html

```
<form method="POST">
    <div class="col-6">
       <label class="form-control-label">Date de début</label>
       <input class="form-control" id="datepicker" type="text" name="date_deb">
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
       <label class="form-control-label">Date de fin</label>
       <input class="form-control" id="datepicker-2" type="text" name="date_fin">
    </div>
    <a type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'export_users_xls' %}">Exporter sous le format excel</a> 
</form>
```

views.py

```
def export_users_xls(request):
   response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/ms-excel')
   response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="contrats.xls"'

   wb = xlwt.Workbook(encoding='utf-8')
   ws = wb.add_sheet('Contrats')

   # Sheet header, first row
   row_num = 0

   font_style = xlwt.XFStyle()
   font_style.font.bold = True

   columns = ['Référence', 'Date de régularisation', "Type d'apporteur", 'Frais de chargement', "Type d'encours", 'Montant Euros', 'Montant UC', 'Montant Prudente']

   for col_num in range(len(columns)):
    ws.write(row_num, col_num, columns[col_num], font_style)

   # Sheet body, remaining rows
   font_style = xlwt.XFStyle()

   date_deb = request.POST.get('date_deb')
   date_fin = request.POST.get('date_fin')

   rows = models.Acte.objects.all().filter(date__range=[date_deb, date_fin]).values_list('ref', 'date', 'apporteur', 'frais', 'type_enc', 'montant_euros', 'montant_uc', 'montant_prud')
   for row in rows:
       row_num += 1
       for col_num in range(len(row)):
           ws.write(row_num, col_num, row[col_num], font_style)

    wb.save(response)
    return response
```

Do you have any idea where that problem could come from?

Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way to get the data to your view is to move your url to the action field in the form, like so

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'export_users_xls' %}">
```

Then just have a button to click. So instead of

```
<a type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'export_users_xls' %}">Exporter sous le format excel</a>
```

try just this

```
<input type="submit" value="Exporter sou le format excel" />
```